# How to edit colliders in Unity2D

Tags: unity, editors

I can edit colliders by holding down the shift key. But when i add a second collider, the shift key always selects the first one. And there is no "Edit Collider" button in the editor (Win/4.5.4f1). I'm testing it with two EdgeColliders2D.

Comment: In Unity 4.6 there's a dedicated button named "Edit Collider" that you could use to edit collider.

Comment: @2600th Make that an answer? (I'm a bit confused though; do you think syloc is using an old Unity version?)

Comment: @Anko Unity3d 4.6 is still in beta. So probably he's not using it.

Comment: @Anko Yeah. I'm not. As I mentioned; I use 4.5.4f1. @2600th; if you post it as an answer, i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unity 4.6 there's a dedicated button in Inspector labeled "Edit Collider" that you could use to edit the collider.

Answer (score -2):

One GameObject can only have one BoxCollider, just choose GameObject you want edit and modify your box collider